# Complex SQL CASE WHEN

Tags: sql

I am trying to do a SELECT using a CASE statement, and I 'm getting errors that do not make sense. My statement appears to adhere to any SQL syntax rules but I'm getting the good ol' "the multi part identifier to_do.[item_id] AND to_do.[item] cannot be bound.
This does not make sense because the column names are correct with respect to the table columns.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT      to_do.[item_id],
            to_do.[item] = CASE to_do.encounter_id WHEN 0 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, e.[date], 101 ) + ' - ' + p.[first_name] + ' ' + p.[last_name] + ' - ' + to_do.[item] AS to_do.[item] ELSE to_do.[item] END,
            to_do.[complete],
            to_do.[encounter_id],
            e.[date],
            p.[last_name] + ', ' + p.[first_name] AS [p_name]
FROM        [dbo].[to_do] LEFT OUTER JOIN
            [dbo].[encounter] e ON
                to_do.[encounter_id] = e.[encounter_id] LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            [dbo].[patients] p ON
                e.[mrn] = p.[mrn]
WHERE       to_do.[user_id] = @user_id
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here ? Based off previous experience I should be able to use CASE like this but maybe I've just been staring at it too long and don't see the obvious.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a table prefix in a column alias `to_do.[item] = CASE ...` is presumably intended to be `[item] = CASE ...`

(Also you have a rogue `AS` in the middle of the `CASE` itself that needs removing)

Answer (score 5):

The `AS {alias}` needs to go after the `END`.  I'd rewrite as follows:

```
SELECT      to_do.[item_id],
            CASE to_do.encounter_id WHEN 0 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, e.[date], 101 ) + ' - ' + p.[first_name] + ' ' + p.[last_name] + ' - ' + to_do.[item] ELSE to_do.[item] END AS [item] , 
...
```

Comment: Nope. `Alias = expression` is perfectly valid for defining a column alias. `AS to_do.[item]` would have the same table prefix problem.

Comment: Good points.  I didn't see the `Alias = expression` form at first.  Edited to clarify.

Comment: +1 Just spotted there is an `AS` in the middle of the `case` as well as the issue in my answer. Looks like your rewrite should sort both problems.

Comment: Ahhh good point. Was doing the same thing twice... Thats what I get for staring at the screen too long.

Answer (score 1):

Your AS is in the wrong place-- try

```
            to_do.[item] = CASE to_do.encounter_id WHEN 0 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, e.[date], 101 ) + ' - ' + p.[first_name] + ' ' + p.[last_name] + ' - ' + to_do.[item] ELSE to_do.[item] END AS to_do.[item] ,
```